# How can I save Image files in in my project folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, openfiledialog

In my Windows application, I have a `PictureBox` and a `Button` control. I want to load an Image file from user from the button's `OnClick` event and save that image file in a folder name "proImg" which is in my project. Then I want to show that image in the `PictureBox`.

I have written this code, but it is not working:

```
OpenFileDialog opFile = new OpenFileDialog();
opFile.Title = "Select a Image";
opFile.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
if (opFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        string iName = opFile.FileName;
        string filepath = "~/images/" + opFile.FileName;
        File.Copy(iName,Path.Combine("~\\ProImages\\", Path.GetFileName(iName)));
        picProduct.Image = new Bitmap(opFile.OpenFile());
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file " + exp.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    opFile.Dispose();
}
```

It's not able to save the image in the "proImg" folder.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: unable to save image in that folder.how can i do this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually the `string iName = opFile.FileName;` is not giving you the full path. You must use the `SafeFileName` instead. I assumed that you want your folder on your `exe` directory also. Please refer to my modifications:

```
OpenFileDialog opFile = new OpenFileDialog();
opFile.Title = "Select a Image";
opFile.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";

string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\ProImages\"; // <---
if (Directory.Exists(appPath) == false)                                              // <---
{                                                                                    // <---
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);                                              // <---
}                                                                                    // <---

if (opFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        string iName = opFile.SafeFileName;   // <---
        string filepath = opFile.FileName;    // <---
        File.Copy(filepath, appPath + iName); // <---
        picProduct.Image = new Bitmap(opFile.OpenFile());
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file " + exp.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    opFile.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: After running please check your /bin folder to see the result.

Comment: but images is not in my ProImages folder. it was in bin/ProImages folder .

Comment: It is going to a PRoImages folder in your /bin/Debug folder aka (executable file directory)

Comment: what if i want to save this path to database, so that later i can use this path to display image.

Comment: You may create one more `string` as `string dbPath = appPath + iName; ` and then store dbPath to your database because it will be contains both directory and file name

Comment: how to do this in separate button? the other button (btnBrowse) loads the image in the picture box, the other button (btnSave) copies the image to the relative folder.

Answer (score 6):

You should provide a correct destination Path to `File.Copy` method. "~\ProImages..." is not a correct path. This example will copy selected picture to folder ProImages inside the project's bin folder :

```
string iName = opFile.FileName;
File.Copy(iName, Path.Combine(@"ProImages\", Path.GetFileName(iName)));
```

the path is relative to current executable file's location, except you provide full path (i.e. @"D:\ProImages").

In case you didn't create the folder manually and want the program generate `ProImages` folder if it doesn't exist yet :

```
string iName = opFile.FileName;
string folder = @"ProImages\";
var path = Path.Combine(folder, Path.GetFileName(iName))
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}
File.Copy(iName, path);
```

PS: Notice the use of [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (`@`) to automatically escape backslash (`\`) characters in string. It is common practice to use verbatim when declaring string that represent path.

Comment: still same type of exception .

Comment: `File.Copy` assume the folder is already exist. If it isn't you need to create the folder first. Is that the case, `ProImages` folder hasn't been created yet?

Answer (score 2):

Try using picturebox.Image.Save function. In my program it is working
PictureBox.Image.Save(Your directory, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

example
pictureBox2.Image.Save(@"D:/CameraImge/"+foldername+"/"+ numbering + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Answer (score 1):

You write code like this.

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) +foldername ;
pictureBox1.Image.Save(appPath + @"\" + filename + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```